# What is our policy on Sock Puppets?

Tags: discussion

I noticed an account a couple weeks ago, that I thought might be a sock puppet.  It had been inactive for a while, so I did not mention it.  The account just made an edit, so I am bringing it up now.

If the accounts I believe may be operated by the same person in fact are, The connection is fairly obvious, though not explicitly defined.

So before I call out any names, what is our policy?

Comment: Why would you think it was a sock puppet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, flag the post for moderator attention and supply what information you have to indicate why you think that. That will keep it private only to the moderating team.

Some useful information can be [found on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sock-puppets).

Comment: As a quick note... the case in question is a false alarm, but the general practice is to flag for attention if you have reason to believe.

Comment: Note also that [you can have multiple accounts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/35607/166646), provided that the two accounts do not interact in any way (i.e. they never, **ever** vote for each other).

Comment: @Beofett my son has a [se] account, but I don't believe he has ever voted, I have voted for his posts, but as I would all newcomer's posts, pretty much get a +1 from me to encourage them. I also disclosed the fact we had two accounts from the same url to the community team. Mind you, he is not very interested in it. I was trying to use Precious as a good example and get him interested in contributing :)